# Multiple hash objects in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two SAS data sets. The first is relatively small, and contains unique dates and a corresponding ID:

```
date   dateID
1jan90     10
2jan90     15
3jan90     20
...
```

The second data set very large, and has two date variables:

```
dt1     dt2
1jan90  2jan90
3jan90  1jan90
...
```

I need to match both `dt1` and `dt2` to `dateID`, so the output would be:

```
id1  id2
10   15
20   10
```

Efficiency is very important here. I know how to use a hash object to do one match, so I could do one data step to do the match for `dt1` and then another step for `dt2`, but I'd like to do both in one data step. How can this be done?

Here's how I would do the match for just `dt1`:

```
data tbl3;
 if 0 then set tbl1 tbl2;

 if _n_=1 then do;
  declare hash dts(dataset:'work.tbl2');
  dts.DefineKey('date');
  dts.DefineData('dateid');
  dts.DefineDone();
 end;

 set tbl1;
 if dts.find(key:date)=0 then output;
 run;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A format would probably work just as efficiently given the size of your hash table...

```
data fmt ;
retain fmtname 'DTID' type 'N' ;
set tbl1 ;
start = date ;
label = dateid ;
run ;
proc format cntlin=fmt ; run ;

data tbl3 ;
  set tbl2 ;
  id1 = put(dt1,DTID.) ;
  id2 = put(dt2,DTID.) ;
run ;
```

Edited version based on below comments...

```
data fmt ;
retain fmtname 'DTID' type 'I' ;
set tbl1 end=eof ;
start = date ;
label = dateid ;
output ;
if eof then do ;
  hlo = 'O' ;
  label = . ;
  output ;
end ;
run ;
proc format cntlin=fmt ; run ;

data tbl3 ;
  set tbl2 ;
  id1 = input(dt1,DTID.) ;
  id2 = input(dt2,DTID.) ;
run ;
```

Comment: Nice solution. Any guidance on how big the lookup table can be for this method? Suppose `tbl1` has 10,000 records... would you still recommend this approach?

Comment: Format and Hash are pretty similar in time for lookup datasets in the thousands.  I don't think you start to run into problems with format until more like hundreds of thousands.  Both work pretty similarly, though, so you probably wouldn't see too much difference at 10,000 records (but of course you should always test for your specific needs).
If you are going to have non-matches, don't forget to include the hlo='o' record in the fmt dataset - this is for non-matches.  Otherwise you get your original value back, which might not be easily verifiable.

Comment: Ran a test with 10,000 in the format dataset and 1 million in the bigger dataset, and it ran pretty similarly.  Format took .57 sec and hash took .45 sec, so perhaps hash is slightly faster, but not a big difference (that small could be random variance in processor load).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Stupid question: As written, this causes the `id` variables to have character values, but I need numeric. Should I just convert them, or is there a way to do the format differently? Thanks.

Comment: INPUT instead of PUT, and create an informat instead of a format.  Type='N' is a format, type='I' (i) is an informat.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have SAS in front of me right now to test it but the code would look like this:

```
 data tbl3;
   if 0 then set tbl1 tbl2;

   if _n_=1 then do;
     declare hash dts(dataset:'work.tbl2');
     dts.DefineKey('date');
     dts.DefineData('dateid');
     dts.DefineDone();
   end;

   set tbl1;

   date = dt1;
   if dts.find()=0 then do;
     id1 = dateId;
   end;

   date = dt2;
   if dts.find()=0 then do;
     id2 = dateId;
   end;

   if dt1 or dt2 then do output; * KEEP ONLY RECORDS THAT MATCHED AT LEAST ONE;

   drop date dateId;
 run;
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the format solution, for one, but if you want to do the hash solution, here it goes.  The basic thing here is that you define the key as the variable you're matching, not in the hash itself.

```
data tbl2;
informat date DATE7.;
input date   dateID;
datalines;
01jan90     10
02jan90     15
03jan90     20
;;;;
run;

data tbl1;
informat dt1 dt2 DATE7.;
input dt1     dt2;
datalines;
01jan90  02jan90
03jan90  01jan90
;;;;
run;
data tbl3;
 if 0 then set tbl1 tbl2;

 if _n_=1 then do;
  declare hash dts(dataset:'work.tbl2');
  dts.DefineKey('date');
  dts.DefineData('dateid');
  dts.DefineDone();
 end;

 set tbl1;
 rc1 = dts.find(key:dt1);
 if rc1=0 then id1=dateID;
 rc2 = dts.find(key:dt2);
 if rc2=0 then id2=dateID;
 if rc1=0 and rc2=0 then output;
 run;
```